# Breeze.js with ASP MVC5 and AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, breeze, entity-framework-6

I'm looking into creating an `ASP MVC5` project (NOT an WebApi, I have to stick with ASP.MVC) with `Breeze.js` and `AngularJS` but I'm facing all kind of problems as the documentation is not complete on achieving this (all new examples are made with WebApi). I created the an MVC controller though the package I found on NuGet (Breeze.WebApi2), so I manage to compile but I'm not sure it actually works anyhow, I have a feeling it's not doing the magic I'm suppose to get. If I go to `http://localhost/breeze/MyBreeze/MetaData`, I get the JSON object of it, cool that part works, though if I try to get Attendees with this `http://localhost/breeze/MyBreeze/Attendees` then the only thing I get is the SQL Query and so not JSON data, which I guess I'm suppose to get..am I? Does `Breeze.WebApi2` and `[BreezeController]` work with ASP MVC5 (again not WebApi)? 

Here is my MVC5 Controller:

```
using Breeze.ContextProvider;
using Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6;
using Breeze.WebApi2;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TemplateBreezeAngularMVC5.Models;

namespace TemplateBreezeAngularMVC5.Controllers
{
    [BreezeController]
    public class MyBreezeController : Controller
    {
        static readonly TimeSpan RefreshRate = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        private static readonly object Locker = new object();
        static DateTime _lastRefresh = DateTime.Now; // will first clear db at Now + "RefreshRate" 
        // static DateTime lastRefresh = DateTime.MinValue; // will clear when server starts

        private readonly EFContextProvider<ConferenceContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<ConferenceContext>();

        public MyBreezeController()
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable Attendees()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Attendees;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable Presentations()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Presentations;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable Speakers()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Speakers;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject modifications)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(modifications);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is also my Angular code, very basic, I just want the query to work and return the data though it fail and returns the query instead, something like `SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], ...` but I guess it's because the MVC Controller isn't working correctly. Here is my Angular code anyway:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('modelLibrary', 'backingStore', true);
//Q.stopUnhandledRejectionTracking();

var myApp =
    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'breeze.angular', 'breeze.directives'])
        .controller("SpeakersCtrl", function ($scope) {
            var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/MyBreeze');

            var query = new breeze.EntityQuery.from("Speakers");
            manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                $scope.results = data.results;
                $scope.$apply();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        });
```

Then my NuGet packages installed are `AngularJS`, `Breeze.Client`, `WebApi2.EF6`, `Breeze.Angular.Directives`, `Breeze.Angular`, `Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6`, `Breeze.Server.ContextProvider`, `Breeze.Server.WebApi2`, `EntityFramework 6.0`, `jQuery`, `Json.NET`, `Q`

I also tried to get the old `HotTowel MVC4` but it's missing lot of things and didn't get it to work.

Edit
It's worth to know that the reason of why I want to use ASP MVC is that my company force me to use it and also because I will NOT make a SPA.

Comment: Finding the hard way, restarting all over and creating a project with WebApi and re-using most of my code and... that works! But I'm not happy about this though, as I really need to make an ASP MVC project. I then don't know what NuGet package to use and how to build the MVC Controller

Comment: The [BreezeController] attribute is strictly Web API. But it all could be easier than you think. Need to know a few things first. What do you mean by "I will NOT make a SPA"? What is Breeze doing for you on the client? Is IQueryable important to you (AFAIK, MVC doesn't support that) or would you be happy with "well-known" query endpoints, supplemented by URL query parameters of your own devising? For a teaser, checkout the "NG6" screen in this [Breeze/MVC mashup on github](https://github.com/wardbell/WorkshopMVC).

Comment: Thanks for your response Ward, I heard a lot about you since Breeze.. ;)  My work restrict me to use ASP MVC only and also because they don't want me to make a SPA (basically for code maintenance if it happen in the future as they are more familiar with it). So with that being said, I want/have to use ASP MVC as the main router and use Angular+Breeze only in some areas whenever I would want to make some dynamic changes in the page. But since I love the idea of Breeze.js with EF and Context object, it all but appeals me to use it... I love the `.saveChanges().then().fail()`

Comment: I'll take a look at your project tomorrow at work.. thanks a lot! I was thinking that I could maybe leave the BreezeController as a WebApi Controller and do regular MVC for the rest, looks like we could mix these type in ASP.MVC, never tried but it seems possible.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly mix MVC and WebApi.  One project I know of has separate MVC `Area`s for each part of the application, and each `Area` has a MVC controller and a WebApi controller, e.g. `CustomerController` and `CustomerApiController`.  The CustomerController loads the initial HTML page (including script bundles), which then can use Breeze to call back to the CustomerApiController.

Comment: @SteeveSchmitt Perfect I got it working by simply changing it to a WebApi Controller, the rest of my project remains an ASP MVC.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, with the help of Steeve Schmitt and Ward, I came up to the conclusion that I can keep my project as an ASP MVC but keep the `BreezeController` as a WebApi Controller. There is no problem into mixing MVC Controller with WebApi Controller. I had to change this:

```
public class MyBreezeController : Controller
```

to this:

```
public class MyBreezeController : ApiController
```

and also make sure to also have the `BreezeWebApiConfig.cs` part of your project with the routing properly setup. And voilà!!!